# Are the statistical assumptions the same between generalized linear models and boosted regression trees?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, boosting

Do machine learning algorithms like Boosted Regression Trees (in the R package (gbm)) follow the same statistical assumptions of not including correlated predictor variables in GLM?

i.e. If I have two correlated predictors (rsq=.7) should I be including both into my BRT model?

Any input or thoughts on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linear regression IS a machine learning algorithm!

Comment: Zack, that still doesnt answer my question, are the statistical assumptions the same between GLM and BRTs?

Comment: Since when does regression _assume_ multi-collinearity?

Comment: Dirk: Ive edited my question.

Comment: LMs and GLMs don't make *any* assumptions, statistical or otherwise, about the relationships among predictors. This is fortunate because pretty much the only time they'll be all neat and uncorrelated is for balanced experimental data.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am mostly concerned because I am using a BRT to predict species richness across a large spatial gradient. As the predictors I am using 10 environmental variables including three temperature climate variables (Mean annual temperature, Max temp of warmest month, Min temp of the coldest month). The three temperature variables are correlated, is it still use to put them all as predictors in my model?

Comment: At least in theory,  correlated variables will greatly reduce the predictive power of the model.  If one is just interested in explaining data, the more variable the merrier. The claim is that boosting greatly increases the robustness of the predictions and that one doesn't need to worry about multicollinearity as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, oh, old question... !

### Linear model

A linear regression model usually has one or more of three purposes:

1. Effect estimation
2. Testing hypotheses
3. Prediction

While there is no multicollinearity assumption behind the classic normal linear model, *strong* multicollinearity *is* problematic regarding the first two items:

- Effect estimates are unnatural due to Ceteris Paribus clause, so are corresponding hypothesis tests.
- Multicollinearity blows up standard errors of estimated effects, which influences p values and confidence intervals accordingly.

*Predictions* are unaffected. So if bullet point 3) is the only purpose of your model, you can usually enjoy life even under strong multicollinearity.

### Boosted trees

**For boosted trees, it is quite the same**:

- If you are only after predictions, multicollinearity is no problem.
- However, if you use your model to derive information on the effects (e.g. by studying partial dependence plots, any sort of variable importance, SHAP decompositions etc.), multicollinearity is similarly problematic as for linear regression.
- You don't do hypothesis tests with boosted trees, so bullet point 2) is irrelevant here.